# Python 3.8 - What's wrong with my dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a text-based PC Building Simulator game and I'm making dictionaries with the different parts and their prices.

```
graphicsCards = {'GTX 1650':159.99, 'GTX 1650 SUPER':169.99, 'GTX 1650 Ti':269.99, 'GTX 1660':220.99, 'GTX 1660 SUPER':239.99, 'GTX 1660 Ti':269.49, 'RTX 2060':319.99, 'RTX 2060 SUPER':399.99, 'RTX 2070':449.99, 'RTX 2070 SUPER':529.99, 'RTX 2080':699.99, 'RTX 2080 SUPER':749.99, 'RTX 2080 Ti':999.99, 'RTX 3070':499.00, 'RTX 3080':699.00, 'RTX 3090': 1,499.00}
```

My code editor won't run the code and says there's a syntax error at the end.
I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 4):

Your editor was right. There is a value at the end without a key.

```
'RTX 3080':699.00, 'RTX 3090': 1,499.00}
                                 ^
```

Most programming languages there days don't allow commas in numbers and instead let you use underscores. I'm not sure if this is true for python, but you could try `1_499.00`. However, I would recommend you just write it as `1499.00`.

**Edit:** I just checked and you can use underscores in numbers with python. However it was more aimed towards binary and hexadecimal numbers that can be hard to read otherwise like `0b1010_1101_0110`.

Comment: I can confirm using underscore works in python.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma in the last number `1,499.00`. You'll have to get rid of commas in any numbers for it to work how you want.

Answer (score 1):

`'RTX 3090': 1,499.00` is the issue. You're separating the digits with a comma, which conflicts with the comma separator for the dictionary values. It thinks you're trying to add a new key/value pair

Answer (score 0):

Your last value entry has a comma in the middle. Use strings or take out the comma.